# Nodemailer transport creation recommendation

Tags: express, typescript, nodemailer

I have a mail service class set up on an express server.

Which method of creating a transport is recommended?

```
class mailService {
    private transport: nodemailer.Transport;
    constructor(){
        this.transport = nodemailer.createTransport('configstring');
    }

    public sendEmail(email: string){
        //send email
    }
}
```

OR

```
class mailService {

    public sendEmail(email: string){
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('configstring');
        //send email
    }

    public sendOtherEmail(email: string){
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('configstring');
        //send email
    }
}
```

The documentation say "You can reuse a transport as often as you like after creating it" Which leads me to think that the first option would be better, however can't tell if there would be any advantage.

Would simply creating the transport every time be an issue of repetition or will there be multiple instances floating around in memory, orphaned every time the `sendEmail` function is executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little advantage in using the second method. It might come in handy if you want to change the transport configuration between different sending jobs.

If that is not the case, it is **recommended** to stick to using a single transport (1st method) for sending emails according to the 
[**DRY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
principle.

You also shouldn't be concerned about memory here because Node has a garbage collector and memory will be freed after your `sendOtherEmail()` function ends.

Comment: To play devils advocate would it not be more fault tolerant to recreate the transporter in each controller request incase the connection fails in some way therefore preventing all email communication from going down as a single connection is not relied on and the communication will resume when connections are successful instead of when the server is restarted?